# ProxyPass Exclude path

Tags: apache, ubuntu, proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

i configured an apache proxy to forward all calls to another web server. I need to exclude the path http://my-server/{var1}/api/{all-path} (where var1 is variable) from this rule.

How can I do?

Thanks

I tried with:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)/api/(.*)$ !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

but not working.

Comment: Not sure what that `ProxyPassMatch` directive is meant to achieve ... The second argument (where you currently have a "!") should be a target URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you need a negative lookahead in your matching pattern and only a single proxy directive:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/[^/]+/(?!api/) http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

That should match any path starting with something and a following slash, followed by anything that is NOT "api/".

Comment: Thanks, finally I figured out the problem: ProxyPassMatch doesn't work with negation.

I solved it like this:

`ProxyPassMatch ^/([^/]+)/api/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1/api/$2` ,
`ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/` ,
`ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/`